# Laravel: Alternative to custom dispatchers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I was using the solution to the [Intercept Laravel Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543301/intercept-laravel-routing) question in Laravel 5.1 and with the update to 5.2, they removed the ability create custom dispatchers.

Have someone find an alternative to create versioned methods?

Answer (score 1):

While not as powerful as a custom dispatcher (I couldn't find the reasoning for its removal), you can override the  [`callAction` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2095048c408c95cb62f9f3cef51e86aaf6fdfad6/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php#L78) in your controllers. This method is called is called by [`ControllerDispatcher::call`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2095048c408c95cb62f9f3cef51e86aaf6fdfad6/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php#L140).

Unfortunately, this method does not change the method used to resolve type-hinted parameters, as that depends on the method name passed to the dispatcher, which I do not see a way to override, but does keep the standard route parameters intact, so you can still load dependencies by yourself (via `app()->make(Dependency::class)`).